# mongodb and js check if the document already exist in the array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

The goal is go check if the course already enrolled by the student.

User Token is saved in the local storage.
I also acquire the _id of the user in the database.

```
let urlValues = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
let id = urlValues.get('courseId')

let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
let userId = localStorage.getItem('id')

let name = document.querySelector("#courseName")
let price = document.querySelector("#coursePrice")
let desc = document.querySelector("#courseDesc")
let enroll = document.querySelector("#enrollmentContainer")

fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/courses/${id}`).then(res => res.json()).then(convertedData => {

    name.innerHTML = convertedData.name 
    price.innerHTML = convertedData.price 
    desc.innerHTML = convertedData.description
    enroll.innerHTML = `
        <a id="enrollButton" class="btn btn-success text-white btn-block">Enroll</a>
    `

    document.querySelector("#enrollButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
        
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/users/enroll', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`//we have to get the actual value of the token value
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                courseId: id
            })
        }).then(res => {
            return res.json()
        }).then(convertedResponse => {
            console.log(convertedResponse)
            if (convertedResponse === true) {
                Swal.fire('Congratulations!',
                `You have successfully enrolled to ${convertedData.name}!`,
                'success')
            } else {
                Swal.fire('Error!',
                `Something went wrong!`,
                'error')
            }
        })
        })
})
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to create a logic that will check if the subject is already enrolled. I already understand the logic however upon execution it's not working.

Comment: Where is `document` coming from, if this is Node.js? Or is this browser code?

Comment: That's a js file.

Comment: That's from mongodb

Comment: Node doesn't understand what `document` is. It's a completely different JS environment from the browser (which does understand what `document` is).

Comment: The initial fetch will get the details of the course, while the second will insert the data in mongodb. I'm having a problem creating a logic that will check if the course already exist or enrolled by the student.

Comment: You're still not explaining how Node comes into this.